# Add Apptentive Survey for Android

Tags: android, survey, apptentive

From the Android Apptentive documentation, only get a callback when a Survey is finished:

```
Apptentive.setOnSurveyFinishedListener(new OnSurveyFinishedListener() {
  @Override
  public void onSurveyFinished(boolean completed) {
    // Your code
  }
});
```

But,I want to get some class like ios:

`ApptentiveSurveyShownNotification/ApptentiveSurveySentNotification`

This way I can get more content than just completed(true/false).
Is there such some class for Android Apptentive?